# Is text recognition by definition a part of image recognition?

Tags: neural-network, cnn, computer-vision, image-recognition

I'm referring to more advanced text recognition systems that are using neural networks to find and extract text from images like the ones Google and Microsoft are offering on their ML platforms.

If not, what is the technical difference to other branches of image recognition like object or face recognition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Please take a look on how to do text recognition in images using [opencv and Tesseract](https://www.learnopencv.com/deep-learning-based-text-recognition-ocr-using-tesseract-and-opencv/) opensource libraries.